# Search for filenames from vector recursively R

Tags: r

I have a list of filenames such as the following spread across subdirectories in a main directory.

```
A.png
B.png
C.png
D.png
```

I have a character vector available with the names of the file:

```
filenames = c("A.png", "B.png", "C.png", "D.png")
```

I am currently trying to use `lapply` along with `dir` to look for the files like so:

```
f1 <- function(x) dir("dirName", pattern = x, recursive = TRUE)

lapply(paste("*", filenames,sep=""), f1)
```

However, it is quite a slow function. I thought of using `*.png` and then matching it but I decided against it because I have many many png files in the directory.

Is there another, possibly more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How many is “many many”? The actual directory traversal is probably the (by far) slowest path, so you really want to do this only once, and then search in the result vector using `grep`. Or generate a single regular expression from the `filenames`, but doing so automatically, correctly, is quite complicated since R doesn’t provide built-in helpers to escape regular expressions and concatenate alternations of sub-expressions.

Comment: I am trying to just use *.png, but it is also REALLY slow (search has been running for 5 minutes now).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what such a regular expression would look like (based on `filenames` above)?

Comment: Why not just `f1("[A-D]\\.png$")`?

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. A-D are just examples. My filenames are actually longer words in reality.